# Manter em array o serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax

No exemplo abaixo, faço o *serialize* e já passo direto em 'data', no ajax:

```
function filtrar() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "text",
        data: $('#filtros').serialize(),
        url: "request.php",
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            $('#result').html(response).show();
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $('#result').html('Erro: ' + thrownError).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Retorno: `Array ( [datai] => 2019-10-29 [dataf] => 2019-10-30 )`

Mas quando passo os valores do `serialize()` por variável, ele perde a estrutura do array:

```
function filtrar() {

    const filtros = $('#filtros').serialize();
    const myData = {'filtros' : filtros};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "text",
        data: myData,
        url: "request.php",
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            $('#result').html(response).show();
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $('#result').html('Erro: ' + thrownError).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Retorno: `Array ( [filtros] => datai=2019-10-29&dataf=2019-10-30 )`

---

- Existe a possibilidade de manter a estrutura de array para passar como variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Victor falou, use `.serializeArray()` mas é preciso criar um JSON para passar no parâmetro `filtros`. É só usar um `.each()` criando os itens da array do JSON:

```
function filtrar() {

    const filtros = $('#filtros').serializeArray();
    const data = {}; // cria o objeto

    // cria o JSON
    $(filtros).each(function(index, obj){
       data[obj.name] = obj.value;
    });

    const myData = { 'filtros': data };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "text",
        data: myData,
        url: "request.php",
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            $('#result').html(response).show();
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $('#result').html('Erro: ' + thrownError).show();
        }
    });
}
```

O resultado será:

```
array(1) { ["filtros"]=> array(2) { ["datai"]=> "2019-10-29" ["dataf"]=> "2019-10-30" } }
```

Comment: Não seria só utilizar o `Json.Parse()` na variável `filtros`?

Comment: Não funciona por que o resultado do serialize é uma URL string, tipo: `datai=valor&dataf=valor`.

Comment: do serialize() sim, mas o do serializaArray() seria elementos do array não?

Comment: Funciona com `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filtros));`, mas a array vai com as chaves `name` e `value`.

Comment: Estou testando enquanto acompanho vocês, e por enquanto, não consegui algo diferente da resposta. Achei que o jQuery teria algo melhor para isso.

Comment: Entendido e obrigado @Sam!

Comment: Espero que tenha te ajudado pelo menos um pouco entao! @rbz

Comment: @Sam Quando uso multiselect ele dá problema. Teria alguma forma pra corrigir?

Comment: @rbz Vou dar uma olhada e depois te falo.

Answer (score 0):

Pode conseguir o mesmo resultado armazenando na variável utilizando o método `serializeArray()`

```js
 const filtros = $('#filtros').serializeArray();
```

Uso desta maneira e funciona muito bem pra mim.

Você pode ver mais na documentação do [**método serializeArray()**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: Victor, não fica o mesmo resultado, ele gera `name` e `value`, aí fica diferente a tratativa.